# How to remove duplicate records from result set of owner

Tags: sql-server, cte, duplication

I'm working with one project like rental agreement system.
There are two roles types of users (User Role)

```
Signer = 0
Observer = 1
```

Anyone can register and create a document(which will be referred as document owner). At a time of creating document,owner can select singers and observers.

Tables:

AspNetUsers

```
╔══════════════════════════════════════╤══════════╗
║ UserID                               │ UserName ║
╠══════════════════════════════════════╪══════════╣
║ 020826F9-B423-4234-B33F-93C15E82BB3E │ Div      ║
╟──────────────────────────────────────┼──────────╢
║ 4613400D-7A5B-4728-B386-2FDB7E909F8D │ Andri    ║
╟──────────────────────────────────────┼──────────╢
║ 33ADA06F-AC92-4DF2-BA43-1A74E84BCD25 │ Katty    ║
╟──────────────────────────────────────┼──────────╢
║ D637CCA3-5E77-4979-A0CE-827057463E56 │ Marina   ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════╧══════════╝
```

Document

```
╔══════════════════════════════════════╤═══════════════════╤══════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Id                                   │ Name              │ CreatedBy                            ║
╠══════════════════════════════════════╪═══════════════════╪══════════════════════════════════════╣
║ DAD61997-F0FC-41C3-B970-009CF8555ADC │ Test document 001 │ 020826F9-B423-4234-B33F-93C15E82BB3E ║
╟──────────────────────────────────────┼───────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────╢
║ D1188225-02BA-49C6-BDB2-01977BF5241C │ Test document 002 │ 020826F9-B423-4234-B33F-93C15E82BB3E ║
╟──────────────────────────────────────┼───────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────╢
║ A1A88DBA-1A7B-47DA-9778-01D889EBD58B │ Test document 003 │ 020826F9-B423-4234-B33F-93C15E82BB3E ║
╟──────────────────────────────────────┼───────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────╢
║ 09DECFA0-C86C-4E70-9BAD-04C399005E28 │ Test document 004 │ 020826F9-B423-4234-B33F-93C15E82BB3E ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════╧═══════════════════╧══════════════════════════════════════╝
```

UserDocumentMapping

```
╔══════════════════════════════════════╤══════════════════════════════════════╤══════════════════════════════════════╤══════╤═══════╗
║ Id                                   │ DocuementId                          │ UserId                               │ Role │ Index ║
╠══════════════════════════════════════╪══════════════════════════════════════╪══════════════════════════════════════╪══════╪═══════╣
║ 714478FA-37B7-424E-8595-017115A628D7 │ DAD61997-F0FC-41C3-B970-009CF8555ADC │ 4613400D-7A5B-4728-B386-2FDB7E909F8D │ 0    │ 1     ║
╟──────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────┼──────┼───────╢
║ FE0C4423-774C-4CFC-9F09-03110BA18493 │ DAD61997-F0FC-41C3-B970-009CF8555ADC │ 33ADA06F-AC92-4DF2-BA43-1A74E84BCD25 │ 0    │ 2     ║
╟──────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────┼──────┼───────╢
║ 19228592-5A68-4090-BA30-03DE1261D0AA │ DAD61997-F0FC-41C3-B970-009CF8555ADC │ D637CCA3-5E77-4979-A0CE-827057463E56 │ 0    │ 3     ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════╧══════════════════════════════════════╧══════════════════════════════════════╧══════╧═══════╝
```

UserDocumentVerification

```
╔══════════════════════════════════════╤══════════════════════════════════════╤═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Id                                   │ UserDocuementMappingId               │ Txhash                                                    ║
╠══════════════════════════════════════╪══════════════════════════════════════╪═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ E1C4D104-E01E-4594-BC3E-0119B28B6313 │ 714478FA-37B7-424E-8595-017115A628D7 │ b39e3c1c6d9cca8c7dac4fabce7849c6b775ec341865fe62180b6fd97 ║
╟──────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╢
║ A82DFDC3-9245-4407-BF4F-01A3E6EA9538 │ FE0C4423-774C-4CFC-9F09-03110BA18493 │                                                           ╢
╟──────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╢
║ 0EC482C4-E842-4736-9FCA-01AD9CB7D389 │ 19228592-5A68-4090-BA30-03DE1261D0AA │                                                           ╢ 
╚══════════════════════════════════════╧══════════════════════════════════════╧═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

The flow is, once user with min-index signed the document, then and then user with next index can see the document. 
E.g: Div created document "Test document 001" with 3 singers: Andri, Katty and Marina.

Now Div can see the document because he is the owner. Andri can also see the document as he is the signer with minimum index, but Katty and Marina will not 
able to see the doc.

Once Andri signed the document, Div, Andri and Katty should able to see the document. 
For that I have wrote query

```
WITH ATC
     AS (
     SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY d.id ORDER BY udv.TxHash DESC) RN,
            D.Id,
            DocumentId,
            udm.[index],
            UDM.UserId,
(
    SELECT MIN(UDM_Next.[index])
    FROM UserDocumentMapping UDM_Next
         INNER JOIN UserDocumentVerification UDV_Next ON UDM_Next.ID = UDV_Next.UserDocumentMappingId
                                                         AND UDV_Next.TxHash IS NULL
                                                         AND UDM_Next.DocumentId = UDM.DocumentId
                                                         AND UDM_Next.[Index] IS NOT NULL
) AS Verified,
            --Name,
            CreatedBy,
            udv.TxHash,                       
            DocumentRole AS DocumentRoleForCurrentUser            
     FROM UserDocumentMapping UDM
          INNER JOIN UserDocumentVerification UDV ON UDM.ID = UDV.UserDocumentMappingId
          INNER JOIN Document d ON udm.DocumentId = d.Id
          INNER JOIN AspNetUsers u ON u.Id = d.CreatedBy
     WHERE UDM.[Index] IS NOT NULL)
     SELECT *
     FROM ATC
     WHERE([Index] <= Verified
           OR Verified IS NULL)
           AND (ATC.UserId = @UserId);
```

This is working fine, but to show the document to the owner(Div in this case) I have added condition.

```
OR ATC.CreatedBy = @UserId
```

This is giving duplicate records to the owner. I have tried to remove duplicate records by `PARTITION BY DocumentId` but in that case signer can't see the document.

So, how can I remove the duplicate records from result set I'm getting?

Comment: Please read [this](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example) and [this](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql). Could you at least please provide a fiddle (dbfiddle.uk for SQL Server is good) for this data? p.s. congrats on 1st question!

Comment: @Vérace, thanks for links, I have never used dbfiddle, will give a try.

Comment: @Vérace: is it unclear to you?

Comment: Choose server, click clear. That gets rid of the blurb. Add your table definitions (use the + signs to add extra `CREATE TABLE` statements). Add your data by `INSERT INTO TABLE (f1, f2...) VALUES (v1, v2...), (v1, v2...);`, not with individual `INSERT`s - sometimes the first one works and the rest silently fail if you put many `INSERT`s into the one section. **Always** check your `INSERT`s with a `SELECT` after (silent failing...) - it's relatively new, but if you bear with the quirks, it's OK! Or, you could try SQLFiddle.com - but that's buggy also and has been unreliable in recent years!

Comment: The question seems fine, but in order to test/run it, I'd have to type out the `CREATE TABLE` statements and then copy and paste in the data - it's easier and less error-prone if the OP does it! It's also polite to give those helping as much info as possible -help us to help you! :-)

Comment: Where was that `OR ATC.CreatedBy = @UserId` added?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ, at here: `WHERE ([Index] <= Verified or Verified is null) and                     
                    (ATC.UserId = @UserId
                    OR ATC.CreatedBy = @UserId)`

Comment: You can try `WHERE (([Index] <= Verified or Verified is null) and ATC.UserId = @UserId) OR (ATC.CreatedBy = @UserId)` but I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks @ypercubeᵀᴹ, but no luck.